# Compile LESS on the client side?

Tags: javascript, css, less

I'm new to LESS. I'm trying to compile less on the client side. I found an article that says to use the below script.

```
    <script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.30.min.js">
    </script>
```

But when I include it in my html  (after the .less file) and open my local file in Chrome. The developer console says: http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.30.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: its not a good practice to do that on client side... it will need time to compile css... do it at server side once and just use the css file.

Comment: Find some [newer tutorial](http://www.cssauthor.com/less-tutorials/).

Answer (score 1):

you can download the latest release from https://github.com/less/less.js/archive/v2.5.1.zip

or

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/less/less.js/master/dist/less.min.js

minified : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/less/less.js/master/dist/less.min.js

### Updated

you have to use you own local server because some browsers will prevent .less serving from `file://` protocol

## To use your own server

1. Install Node
2. `npm install http-server -g`

then go to you folder using your console

3. `http-server`

now you can use `http://localhost:8080` as your own server and .less will work

Comment: I have downloaded the latest release as suggested by Ammaroff. When I link it in my html file.
        <script src="less.min.js"></script>
I get this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load. 
Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: this because you are trying to load your .less file from `file://` and chrome is blocking this. So the best way is to use you local server, the easiest way is having node and from you console `npm install http-server -g` then open you folder and `http-server`

Comment: Don't suggest "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/..." for external usage - GitHib is *not* CDN!

Comment: actually `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.min.js"></script>` from documentation and @sic1 answer is what should be used , but I added the github code to download and then include it as local asset

Answer (score 1):

You want to compile on your local machine, then push the compiled file up to the server. And then you want to make sure that your CSS file references that compiled file.

The LESS docs recommend this java script to compile on your computer: http://lesscss.org/#download-options-browser-downloads

Or you can do the compile on client side approach, but you should update your script to use `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.min.js"></script>`, [the CDN link](http://lesscss.org/#download-options--less-cdn-cdnjs-cloudflare-com-ajax-libs-less-js-2-5-1-less-min-js-) from their site.

I'd still urge you to compile on your local machine, as this saves lots of precious time that your page would be without any styles. This article sums up other ways to go about a more robust build process.

Comment: Edited your answer 1. To remove Rhino script link (because it's a script for Java Rhino environment and no way a script recommended outside of Java). 2. Fixed other links.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [the docs](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage) for usage. Download the `less.js` file and refer to it using `<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

I made the example already mentioned using the **link tag**, but I also leave the example with the **style tag** that makes testing in development much easier.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <!-- example with link tag -->
    <link href="css/app.less" rel="stylesheet/less">

    <!-- example with style tag -->
    <style type="text/less">
        html {
            body {
                background-color: red;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <!-- The library automatically converts <link> tags -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/4.1.3/less.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Convert style tags -->
    <script>
        const lessStyles = document.querySelectorAll('style[type="text/less"]')
        lessStyles.forEach(styleElement => {
            const lessCode = styleElement.innerText
            less.render(lessCode, (error, output) => {
                const cssCode = output.css
                styleElement.innerText = cssCode
                styleElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/css')
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

```js
// Convert style tags
const lessStyles = document.querySelectorAll('style[type="text/less"]')
lessStyles.forEach(styleElement => {
  const lessCode = styleElement.innerText
  less.render(lessCode, (error, output) => {
    const cssCode = output.css
    styleElement.innerText = cssCode
    styleElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/css')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/4.1.3/less.min.js"></script>

<head>
    <!-- example with link tag -->
    <link href="css/app.less" rel="stylesheet/less">

    <!-- example with style tag -->
    <style type="text/less">
        html {
            body {
                background-color: red;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
```